# Category attributes are not updating

Tags: category

I'm having a problem where my category attributes (name, url, etc) are not updating in the front end of the store, as well as new products that are added to that category are not displaying. In the admin area, the products show as being assigned to that category and the name of the category is changed, however this is not reflected on the front end of the site. I've done the usual things, flush cache, make sure the root category is set for the store, make sure that the categories are children of the root category, but no luck. New categories that are created also go straight to a 404 page.

Is there any reason why the changes would reflect in the admin area but not the front end? Thanks for any guidance that you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric storm,it may be

**1**)indexing issue ,so `you need to reindexing` from

```
Product Flat Data 
Category Flat Data  
Category Products 
from index management
```

**2**)if you have  not `selecting  product Website  so, goto manage product>click on a product>goto website tab and select websit`e.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the quantity and stock availability of the products? It should have at least one and stock availability is in stock.